# Cloning / Reading only history /log of a git repository

Tags: git

Within a locally cloned git repository I can watch the history with

```
git log
```

In a small tool I only need the history of a repository, not the code.
Is there a way to clone a repository without the code (history only)?

Is there any other way to get the history only from a git repository?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Clone the repository with the `--bare` flag:

```
git clone --bare ...
```

> A **"bare" repository** in Git **just contains the version control
>   information** and no working files (no tree) and it doesn't contain the
>   special .git sub-directory. Instead, it contains all the contents of
>   the .git sub-directory directly in the main directory itself.

Read more in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---bare) on it, or this helpfull page about [setting up server environments](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server) using the option.

Comment: Bare repos are also useful if you want to have a centralized location to push and pull from, but that you will not be developing in.

Comment: This does not work, the clone still does request and receive objects for me.

Comment: @Andry How is that related to the question and why do you want Git to not transfer objects? Git stores all information in the filesystem (see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) but with the `--bare` flag it won't check out the working copy files. Nonetheless, it still has to manage version information etc. and stores that as "objects".

Comment: @CoDEmanX This IS related to the question in the title. And because a user not always need the objects to read/get the history. And with the `--bare` flag it makes almost the same amount of a network traffic. And objects actually are not needed to fetch the history.

Comment: @Andry OP doesn't ask for saving network traffic. Also, commit information is stored in commit _objects_ and file names are tracked using tree _objects_ (`git log --name-only` does list file names). I don't know of a built-in way to suppress content objects, if that is even possible without corrupting the filesystem database. You might be able to reduce network traffic using `--reference` or other advanced options, but the best option is probably to use a Git server with web UI (can be GitHub) which allows you to view the history without cloning anything to your local computer.

Comment: @CoDEmanX Requesting only history/log automatically means a significally reduced traffic. Not file names nor commit objects are not needed to send over the network to see a set of commit log entries with timestamps or whatever else.

Comment: @Andry Well, that's not how Git works I'm afraid. And saving disk space and CPU cycles by ditching the working copy checkout is also a legitimate solution to the question how to "clone a repository without the code". If you look for something else, then post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Combining the `--bare` and `--filter=blob:none` options on clone gives you the full logs while omitting the objects thus minimizing space for commit history:

```
git clone --bare --filter=blob:none ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to view the history, you can use the partial clone feature with filtering out the blobs(file contents).

> git clone --filter=blob:none YOUR_GIT_URL

Ref:

1. [git clone --filter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---filterltfilter-specgt)
2. [Get up to speed with partial clone and shallow clone](https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/)