# git log a specific file without cloning the entire repo

Tags: git

I have a very large repo due to its long history and I want to get the logs of a certain directory in my git tree without cloning or with cloning the minimum required files. According to https://rukman7.github.io/2020/08/13/Git-history.html I can clone the code only using

```
git clone --bare --single-branch $GIT_BASE
```

I tried doing that although I know that's not the optimum scenario in my case (the code is not so large compared to the git repo  history).
And according to that question [Cloning / Reading only history /log of a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253420/cloning-reading-only-history-log-of-a-git-repository) I can get the log of a specific dir using

```
git log -1 --pretty='format:%ci' dir/
```

My issue is when I run that first command I don't get the tree of the files so using the second command returns

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'dir/': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Is there a way to run git log without cloning the entire repo?

Comment: `git clone --bare --single-branch $GIT_BASE` is cloning the repo. It's right there in the command. It's just reducing the portion of the graph that gets transferred.

Comment: You're correct, I modified the question. Thanks!

Comment: Try to remove `--bare`. It means "no working directory"

Comment: Because you have no work-tree, you'll need to specify pathspecs after a `--` option: `git log ... -- path/to` for instance. (Note: that's suggested right there in the error message.) You may also need to specify a proper starting point commit (the named branch you used for your single-branch clone); the bare repo is likely to have `HEAD` set inappropriately.