# Is git-clone-bare-filter-blob-none sufficient to do rev-list-all-count?

Tags: git, git-clone

My situation is that I have:

- a multi-100MB repo and
- *all* I want to do is run `git rev-list --all --count`
- on *a clean machine*, that is, the initial/repeated clone of the repo is a significant overhead.

I have already found that

```
# Slow:
# git clone "https://mybitbucket.corp.net/scm/PRJ/repo.git"

# Much better:
git clone --bare --filter=blob:none "https://mybitbucket.corp.net/scm/PRJ/repo.git"
cd repo
git rev-list --all --count
```

**seems** to work a charm.

However, as it is with such things, works-on-my-system doesn't mean that this is

- a good idea in general with current git versions (2.35+)
- has no unintended corner cases
- given my context of running with git on Windows and Bitbucket as server

I have found several question here that describe exactly that, as well as the current docs:

- [Do GitHub and GitLab support git clone's --filter parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55195590/do-github-and-gitlab-support-git-clones-filter-parameter)
- [Git clone bare repo without blobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232037/git-clone-bare-repo-without-blobs)
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---filterltfilter-specgt
- [Cloning / Reading only history /log of a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253420/cloning-reading-only-history-log-of-a-git-repository)

So, it would seem to me that this is indeed the way to go, so this is really to make sure from a git noob that this is a sane thing to do. :-)

Comment: Personally my only caution would be to make sure I'm always using a recent enough git client. If you have the exact version of that under control (such as running this in a known docker image or similar), then I see no reason not to do this. In fact, you might even get away with [a tree-less clone](https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/) for this use case, which would speed things up even further.

Comment: You might be able to go further and use a treeless clone: https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/

Comment: Holy moly that https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/ is a great article. I could've used that 3h ago! :-)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, according to GitHub blog article [Get up to speed with partial clone and shallow clone](https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/), this is indeed a feasible approach.

They describe `git clone --filter=blob:none <url>` to create a "blobless" clone and also **`git clone --filter=tree:0 <url>`** which is even less work and should suffice for `git rev-list --all --count`.